# Why does motion compensation need a decoder?

Tags: compression

I know that motion compensation is the process of using the motion estimaton MV information and then compensating it to describe only the differences between reference frame and the motion estimation mv.

Why do we need the decoder to do this motion compensation. We already have the reference frame and the motion vectors. We just need to translate and then send the residual information over as encoded bits.